# Can window Selection object be invalidated?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code that queries the Selection object by using window.getSelection(). If i make a selection, then window.getSelection() successfully returns the Selection parameters, however, if i invalidate the selection by clicking anywhere else on the screen, window.getSelection() keeps giving me the old Selection object.

I'm not building something big, so i don't want to install a library like Rangy or whatever. How can i invalidate the selection object? By the way, i'm using Firefox 20.0.1 for this script.

Please any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click elsewhere in the text, `getSelection` doesn't give you the old selection object but an empty one. You can test the length of `selection.toString()`.

```
var selectionIsNotEmpty = selection.toString().length>0;
```

On WebKit browsers, your selection's type changes also from "Range" to "Caret" or "None".

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uwahog/3/edit) (select something then click elsewhere)

Comment: How do you test for the Selection object type? i used instanceof but the Caret type does not exist.

Comment: I use the `type` property. See demo. You can also test the length of the selection.

Comment: The type property works great on Chrome, but it is undefined on Firefox. Do you something that's cross-browser?